# Friendly_id User or Profile model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I have User(has_one :profile) model linked to a Profile(belongs_to :user) model.

I will use username to slug profile url, the friendly shoud be implemented in User or Profile model?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the name column in user or profile?

Answer (score 0):

I would still add it to `Profile`, because you need it to build a `profile_url`, not an `user_url`, but then delegate `username` to `User`:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId

  belongs_to :user

  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged
  delegate :username, to: :user

  # ...
end
```